# Why is the upper row in (III.21) a distinguished triangle?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-categories

I am reading Methods of Homological Algebra from Gelfand/ Manin.

In chapter three (Derived categories and derived functors) in the section 4 (Derived categories as the localization of the Homotopic Category) they prove that the class of quasi-isomorphisms in the homotopy category are localising.
On page 161, they say that the upper row in (III.21) a distinguished triangle.
Could someone help me see why? I see that the row below is one (it's even a strict triangle) but they are not isomorphic.

I guess it must be something easy and quick to answer.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what $\pi g$ is or how it relates to $g,$ but this just looks like the triangle associated to the mapping cone of $\pi g.$

Comment: Looks like $\pi g$ is the composition of $\pi$ and $g$, and indeed the upper row should be the triangle of the mapping cone of $\pi g$.